# R 4.0.3 inline compile fails on macos 11.0 based on math.h

Tags: c++, r, inline

should the following not *just work* (TM Apple)?

```
library(inline)

hello <- cxxfunction( signature( a="numeric"), plugin="Rcpp", body='
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Hello";
')

hello( 15.0 )
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the lovely error message:

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  In file included from file10b7a11619550.cpp:4:In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27:In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:29:In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:67:In file included 
from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100:In file included from /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:308:/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/math.h:300:15:
 fatal error: 'math.h' file not found#include_next <math.h>
              ^~~~~~~~1 error generated.make: *** [file10b7a11619550.o] Error 1
```

this is using plain macos 11.0, which comes with xcode 12.2.  as far as I can see, nothing on macos that requires programming just works any longer, starting with openMP.

what is the recommended fix for this problem?  pointers appreciated.

Comment: As an aside: [You should never use `std::cout`. Use `Rcpp::Rcout`.](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-rcout/)

Comment: I would reinstall Xcode from the AppStore and maybe install command-line tools from Apple's developer site. I think I read something like this in the macports instructions.

Comment: And `evalCpp("2 + 2")` is a more compact test for `Rcpp`.  The `inline` package is clearly dominated by `Rcpp Attributes`, and has been since 2013.  As for macOS setup, the best bet may still be https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, [post an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow), don't edit the question

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to update to the last version **and** remove `~/.R/Makevars` and `~/.Renviron`.  It may also entail adding a link to make sure that math.h is findable.

A better quick test is `evalCpp("2 + 2")`.